# Regex match in string

Tags: regex, kotlin

I would like to extract two numbers for a strings by regex "[0-9]+"

```
var str = "ABcDEFG12345DiFKGLSG938SDsFSd"
```

What I want to extract is "12345" and "938".

But I am not sure how to do so in Kotlin.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher
import java.util.regex.Pattern

fun main(args:Array<String>) {
val p = Pattern.compile("\\d+")
val m = p.matcher("ABcDEFG12345DiFKGLSG938SDsFSd")
while (m.find())
{
  println(m.group())
}
}
```

`Pattern.compile("\\d+")`, it will extract the digits from the expression.

Comment: You could make this approach more Kotlin idiomatic using `val p = Regex("\\d+")`, `val s = "ABcDEFG12345DiFKGLSG938SDsFSd"` and then `pattern.findAll(s).forEach { println(it.value) }`.